# Creating a cache, how to check element presence?

Tags: http, caching

I am creating a non-persistent cache system using java, in order to store HTTP responses and I think I could use a map for storing cached content.

What is unclear to me is how to check if a requested element is present or not.
I thought it could be an idea to begin considering the address of the requested resource, but I think it is not sufficient, because apart the requested resource the HTTP request may have also cookies, which could be different for each request...

I tried to find a manual explaining how to manage caches but I found nothing.

Could you help me to find a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Try to generate a request fingerprint and identify requests by that. The fingerprint must be computed based on all information present during the request. Typically you will use a hash of such a fingerprint as key inside a map.

Comment: Do you think this is sufficient? Or should I have to consider something else for defining the key?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, what 'something' might exist that influences request results apart from "all information present" ? ;-)

Comment: I want to identificate a cache "line" by the request, not by the response :)

Comment: Sure, that's why I wrote to use a 'request fingerprint' as key. I would expect a requests response to be identical if all information given at the time of the request is identical. I would be alarmed if that is not the case.

Comment: Ok, I will start considering just the request string (with its parameters) and cookies. Hoping this is sufficient!

Thanks!

Comment: There might be other information that influences the response. But that is something you must know yourself. It is your scripts processing the requests. Are there any external information sources used? Anything time based? Worm holes that might insert a response into itself again?

Comment: @arkascha I think your first comment amounts to an actual answer...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's note down for the records all we put together during the discussion:

Generate a request fingerprint and identify further requests by that. The fingerprint must be computed based on all information present during the request. Typically you will use a hash of such a fingerprint as key inside a map. 
Since a response to identical requests should be identical the cached response should be a correct reply to an second identical request, where identity is matched by identical keys being generated.

For storage of cache data two setups come into mind:

- Cache is kept in a database. This promises a good performance and allows to store additional information alongside finderprint and content: time of expidation, additional headers, ...
- File system based: each response is stored in a file, files are named by fingerprint. Question is how to store additional information, if such is required.